# startup scripts on Google cloud platform using Packer

Tags: google-cloud-platform, terraform, google-compute-engine, packer

Im using hashicorp's Packer to create machine images for the google cloud (AMI for Amazon). I want every instance to run a script once the instance is created on the cloud. As i understand from the Packer docs, i could use the `startup_script_file` to do this. Now i got this working but it seems that the script is only runned once, on image creation resulting in the same output on every running instance. How can i trigger this script only on instance creation such that i can have different output for every instance?

packer config:

```
{
    "builders": [{
        "type": "googlecompute",
        "project_id": "project-id",
        "source_image": "debian-9-stretch-v20200805",
        "ssh_username": "name",
        "zone": "europe-west4-a",
        "account_file": "secret-account-file.json",
        "startup_script_file": "link to file"
    }]
  }
```

script:

```
#!/bin/bash

echo $((1 + RANDOM % 100)) > test.log #output of this remains the same on every created instance.
```

Comment: I have replicated your packer config and startup script on my end and it displayed a different number every time I build a new instance from Packer. Can you advise how exactly you build the VM's? The command you uses and how many VM's are you creating?

Comment: So i create a machine image using Packer once. Then i reuse this image to create multiple instances resulting in the same output on each instance. I am not running `packer build` for each instance i create, as i understand you are doing right?

Comment: Thanks for the clarification, the `startup script` that was set on the creation of the VM Instance is not included in the Image that you created, since that was setup outside the OS environment. To be able to have a `startup script` on your new Image, you will need to set it up inside the OS first by using a [cron job](https://www.tecmint.com/auto-execute-linux-scripts-during-reboot-or-startup/) or other method. Then from there, you can create the base Image.